# Desire2Learn Valence API user ID

Tags: desire2learn

What is the preferred method for obtaining the user ID used in the following Valence Grades API?

PUT /d2l/api/le/(D2LVERSION: version)/(D2LID: orgUnitId)/grades/(D2LID: gradeObjectId)/values/(D2LID: userId)

Is the user id here the same as the token ID received during authentication, or do you call the "whoami" API, or is it something else?

Answer (score 1):

The "whoami" call provides data on the current UserContext you are working in (the token value you get back during the auth step). For example, if you are logged in as an Administrator, that would provide back the Administrator's userId.

[WhoAmI API Call](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/user.html#get--d2l-api-lp-%28D2LVERSION-version%29-users-whoami)

```
GET /d2l/api/lp/(D2LVERSION: version)/users/whoami
```

This will give you the information on the current UserContext

```
{
    "Identifier": "<string:D2LID>",
    "FirstName": "<string>",
    "LastName": "<string>",
    "UniqueName": "<string>",
    "ProfileIdentifier": "<string:D2LID>"
}
```

If you are looking for the UserIds for the users in a particular orgUnit, I would make the following call:

[Classlist API Call](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/enroll.html#get--d2l-api-le-%28D2LVERSION-version%29-%28D2LID-orgUnitId%29-classlist-)

```
GET /d2l/api/le/(D2LVERSION: version)/(D2LID: orgUnitId)/classlist/
```

This will give you an array of ClasslistUsers

```
{
    "Identifier": "<string:D2LID>",
    "ProfileIdentifier": "<string:D2LID>",
    "DisplayName": "<string>",
    "UserName": "<string>|null",
    "OrgDefinedId": "<string>|null",
    "Email": "<string>|null"
}
```

The "Identifier" value in either case is the one you will want to use for (D2LID:UserId)

Comment: How do I retrieve this "Identifier" value for the user associated with the token value retrieved during the auth step?  From the above, it sounds like you are saying I need to call the "whoami" API.

Comment: If you are looking to find out the authed user's ID, you would use the whoami call. In the example API call where you were updating a grade item I assumed you would be modifying someone else's grade value, not the logged in users.